# How do I include group count?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The first SQL statement groups my result set by col5, as expected. I'd like to include the count of each row in the group so I use the second SQL statement.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, Q1.col5, col6
FROM TABLE_NAME, 
   (SELECT col5 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col6 = 123456 GROUP BY col5) Q1
WHERE col6 = 123456 AND TABLE_NAME.col5 = Q1.col5;


SELECT count(1), col1, col2, col3, col4, Q1.col5, col6
FROM TABLE_NAME, 
   (SELECT col5 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE col6 = 123456 GROUP BY col5) Q1
WHERE col6 = 123456 AND TABLE_NAME.col5 = Q1.col5;
```

When I run the second statement, I get `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. How do I add a column that contains the count of rows in each group?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected output? That would clear things up much more..

Comment: Firstly, `count(1)` has no affect on performance, so doesn't matter if you use `count(*)`. Secondly, count as an **aggregate_expression** expects a group by the columns you mention int he **Select list** I would have answered, however, I would first expect you to provide a test case.

Comment: And, to have a running count for each row, use the **Analytic COUNT() OVER()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your single requirement:
"add a column that contains the count of rows in each group?"

You could do this:

```
  with w_data as (
           select 123 col1, 234 col2, 345 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 123 col1, 345 col2, 456 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 567 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 789 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 890 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual
           )
  select col5, count(*)
    from w_data
   where col6 = 123456
   group by col5
   order by col5
  /
```

Results

```
        COL5   COUNT(*)
  ---------- ----------
         345          2
         456          2
         678          3

  3 rows selected.
```

However, that doesn't return any other columns ..., so you could handle that using analytics
(note: this one is same as Sander's answer )

```
  with w_data as (
           select 123 col1, 234 col2, 345 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 123 col1, 345 col2, 456 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 567 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 789 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 890 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual
           )
  select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,
         count(*) over (partition by col5) cnt
    from w_data
   where col6 = 123456
  /
```

Results:

```
              COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4       COL5       COL6        CNT
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         123        234        345        123        345     123456          2
         123        345        456        123        345     123456          2
         234        456        567        123        456     123456          2
         234        456        678        123        456     123456          2
         345        567        678        123        678     123456          3
         345        567        789        123        678     123456          3
         345        567        890        123        678     123456          3

  7 rows selected.
```

However, that returns repeated values of the count for each group (so if the group where col5 = 345 has 2 rows, you get count of 2, and 2 rows showing the count of 2.)

If you really just wanted the latest, most recent, etc, row in each group .. you could also go one step further:

```
  with w_data as (
           select 123 col1, 234 col2, 345 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 123 col1, 345 col2, 456 col3, 123 col4, 345 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 567 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 234 col1, 456 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 456 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 678 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 789 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual union all
           select 345 col1, 567 col2, 890 col3, 123 col4, 678 col5, 123456 col6 from dual
           ),
     w_sub as (
        select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,
               count(*) over (partition by col5) cnt,
               row_number() over (partition by col5 order by col1 desc, col2 desc, col3 desc ) rnum
          from w_data
         where col6 = 123456
       )
  select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, cnt
    from w_sub
   where rnum = 1
  /
```

Results:

```
        COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4       COL5       COL6        CNT
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         123        345        456        123        345     123456          2
         234        456        678        123        456     123456          2
         345        567        890        123        678     123456          3

  3 rows selected.
```

(in all above queries, "w_data" is just some "fake" data I created)

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball said that you mean something like

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 
       count(*) over (partition by col5)
from table_name
where col6 = 123456
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Exactly what I suggested.